# Python: How split data into different data types into 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, split

I’m trying to split downloaded data to an 2D array into different datatypes. The downloaded data looks like this:

```
000|17:40
000|17:45
010|17:50
025|17:55
056|18:00
178|18:05
202|18:10
203|18:15
190|18:20
072|18:25
013|18:30
002|18:35
000|18:40
000|18:45
000|18:50
000|18:55
000|19:00
000|19:05
000|19:10
000|19:15
000|19:20
000|19:25
000|19:30
000|19:35
000|19:40
```

I’m using the following code to parse this into a two dimensional array:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://gps.buienradar.nl/getrr.php?lat=52&lon=4')
html = response.read()
htmlsplit = []

for record in html.split("\r\n"):
    htmlsplit.append(record.split("|"))

print htmlsplit
```

This is working great, but as expected, it treats it as a string. I’ve found some examples that splits into integers. That’s great if both sides where integers. But in my case it’s an integer | string (or maybe some kind of Python time format)

How can I split this directly into different data types?

Comment: What kind of array? module array.array (weird)? List? Numpy array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for record in html.split("\r\n"):  # beware, newlines are treacherous!
    s = record.split("|")
    htmlsplit.append((int(s[0]), s[1]))
```

Just write a parser for each record, if you have data this simple. However, I would add some try/except clause to catch errors for non-conforming lines, empty lines, etc. which may be present in the data. The code above is very fragile. Also, you might want to break at only `\n` and then clean your strings by strip() (i.e. replace `s[1]` by `s[1].strip()`). The integer conversion takes care of it automatically.

Comment: Hi DrV, Thank you! I've changed it into this:
`for record in html.splitlines():
 s = record.split("|")
 htmlsplit.append((int(s[0]),s[1]))`

Used splitlines from the advice from Aron Hall below. And added the `:` you forgot ;)

One question, do I need to "free"  the temporary "s" to rule out memory leaks?

Comment: I will use try/except, thanks for pointing that out. (This is my first time on Stackoverflow) but what a horrible reply editor is this. I hope I can make sense without the line-breaks)

Comment: @Satoer I just omitted tho colon to see if you are awake :) (Fixed now.) No need to free variables in python; if you are not using them anymore (no-one references to them), a big yellow lorry with the text "Garbage Collector" comes and picks them us. I suggest you do some reading on GC and python's "everything is an object" model, as understanding the basics is sometimes useful. BTW, Aaron Hall's solution is in a way more pythonic than mine; once you learn the basics, you'll learn to love the nice modules available!

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.splitlines` instead of splitting on `\r\n`
Use the `csv` module to iterate over the lines:

```
import csv
txt = '000|17:40\n000|17:45\n000|17:50\n000|17:55\n000|18:00\n000|18:05\n000|18:10\n000|18:15\n000|18:20\n000|18:25\n000|18:30\n000|18:35\n000|18:40\n000|18:45\n000|18:50\n000|18:55\n000|19:00\n000|19:05\n000|19:10\n000|19:15\n000|19:20\n000|19:25\n000|19:30\n000|19:35\n000|19:40\n'

reader = csv.reader(txt.splitlines(), delimiter='|')
column1 = []
column2 = []
for c1, c2 in reader:
    column1.append(c1)
    column2.append(c2)
```

You can also use the `DictReader`

```
import StringIO
reader2 = csv.DictReader(StringIO.StringIO(txt), 
                         fieldnames=['int', 'time'], 
                         delimiter='|')

column1 = []
column2 = []
for row in reader2:
    column1.append(row['time'])
    column2.append(row['int'])
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the " splitlines"  advice. I've discovered that this keeps the array free from a closing empty record.

Thanks for the solution, but the solution from DrV does exactly what I need.